# embedded video get url

Tags: python, video, kodi

Ok, I have been scratching my head on this for way too long. I am trying to retrieve the url for an embedded video on a web page using Beautiful Soup and requests modules in Python 2.7.6. I inspect the html in chrome and I can see the url to the video but when I get the page using requests and use Beautiful Soup I can't find the "video" node. From looking at the source it looks like the video window is a nested html document. I have searched all over and can't find out why I can't retrieve this. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

here is the url to one of the videos:

http://goldfilmesonline.com/doutor-estranho-legendado-online/

i see someone answer the same question, can someone help me too please

Comment: what is the video URL you're looking for? is it http://thevid.net/e/3ak5tsm4gliixx65avmexxn/?

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

a = requests.get('http://goldfilmesonline.com/doutor-estranho-legendado-online/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(a.content, 'lxml')
links = soup.find_all('iframe')
for i in links:
    print(i['src'])
```

I think these are the links you're talking about. This code prints:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/iysJOCcbLHw
https://openload.co/embed/J5-ympmuH-4/
http://thevid.net/e/3ak5tsm4gliixx65avmexxn/
```

Comment: thanks man , but it dindt work in my vlc i was try to get the link to play but they dont play there do u know any thing about it

Comment: I think you have to download them in order to play on VLC, as far as I know you have to access these links in a browser.

Comment: Rafael your code give me 3 links , let's do 1 at a time, if I play https://openload.co/embed/J5-ympmuH-4/ that is your 2 link, and I go to inspect element-network-media it give 2 links that are URL Request they both work in VLC, how Python can get to this link I think we have to send some parameters maybe the ip I don't know, I want to see your code and try to do by myself on the others links.

Comment: I apologize for the dumb questions man I m just a noob try to learning, I did all the basics tutorials in you tube but how much more I study more questions I have do u know any advance tutorial in python